# How to have a numerical change in one cell affect another cell's numerical value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm attempting to generate an inventory sheet for my work place and one of the columns is the inventory of the warehouse, another is the inventory of what we have in store. When subtracting from the warehouse inventory, I would like to have Excel automatically add a fixed value to the store inventory. This will save us time when performing updates to the sheet's data.

Would this be possible and how would it be accomplished?

Comment: It could be accomplished, either with formulas or with VBA, depending on the details of what you want.

Comment: Easily possible. Please edit your question to provide sample data and a example result together with what you have tried and you will probably get the help you need quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You should do like, at one place you should have the inventories data which are currently in the use, while at another place you should have the inventories data which are currently not in use and in the store. After that you can do a total of both the data values to get a final total of the inventories. According to me, this is could be the simplest way to do a **Inventory Management** using **Excel**.